# The value of dropdown to be displayed on select of other dropdown js

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

```
<html>
<select id="degree_id" onchange=geneCourse(this.value);>
    <option value="1">BE</option>
    <option value="2">MBA</option>
</select>
<select id="course_id">
    <option value="10">A</option>
    <option value="20">none</option>
</select>
</html>
<script>
function geneCourse(degree){
    var degree = $('#degree_id option:selected').text();
    if(degree == 'MBA')               
    {
        $("#course_id option:contains('none')").prop("selected", true);
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried the above code and it doesnt work :(
If MBA is selected ,by default it should be "none" for the second drop down.....
*However it is a repeated question,i couldn't figure out a proper solution for this....*
**Your help is much appreciated.**

Thanks in advance,
Passioncoder.

Comment: Not working in chrome as well for me.

Answer (score 0):

use this solution .

```
  $("#course_id option:contains('none')").attr("selected", true);
```

you might be using older jquery lib.

Comment: The version is 1.8.2.It doesn't give any error,it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```
<html>
    <select id="degree_id" onchange="geneCourse(this);">
        <option value="BE">BE</option>
        <option value="MBA">MBA</option>
    </select>
    <select id="course_id">
        <option value="10">A</option>
        <option value="20">none</option>
    </select>
</html>
<script>
function geneCourse(element){
    var degree = $(element).val();
    if(degree == 'MBA')               
    {
        $("#course_id option:contains('none')").prop("selected", true);
    }
}
</script>
```

You can refer to the sample [JSFiddle Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/kDFtY/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.As per your JSFiddle code,It gets the val as MBA and it checks the condition as well,but   $("#course_id option:contains('none')").prop("selected", true); is not working....None is not popping up in the second drop down.